# Is there an easy way to read the appsettings of a web.config file just by using it's path?

Tags: .net, web-config, configurationmanager

This seemed to me like an easy one, but I can't seem to find the correct google query to help me out..

I have *some* web.config file located in C:\temp and would like to be able to use something like `myWebConfig.AppSettings["myParam"]`.
Can this be done?

I tried using `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration`, `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`, `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration` and `WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration`.

Maybe I'm just not using those in a correct way or..?

**[Update]**
What tvanfossen wrote is as good as correct. I don't have edit privileges so I will write the code I used in the end here.

```
/* Method based on what I found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339167/how-to-read-a-configuration-section-from-xml-in-a-database/4844365#4844365
 * and tvanvossens answer.
 * There's probably room for improvement, but it does what I need now.
 */
private static T GetSection<T>(string pathToWebConfigFile, string configNode) where T : ConfigurationSection, new()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(pathToWebConfigFile);
    var element = doc.Element("configuration").Element(configNode);
    var reader = element.CreateReader();
    var settingsSection = new T();
    settingsSection.GetType().GetMethod("DeserializeSection", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(settingsSection, new object[] { reader });
    return settingsSection;
}
```

usage example:

```
var settingsSection = GetSection<AppSettingsSection>(pathToWebConfigFile, "appSettings");
var connectionStringSection = GetSection<ConnectionStringsSection>(pathToWebConfigFile, "connectionStrings");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "easy."  I think it could be done using reflection, but it wouldn't be particularly flexible.

First you'd open up the document as XML and find the `appSettings` section. Then you'd create an XmlReader for that section.  Then, create an AppSettingsSection and invoke the DeserializeSection() method using reflection with the reader as the argument.  You might to use Reflector to see how ConfigurationManager does this as there may be other methods on the AppSettingsSection that need to be invoked to complete the loading of the section.

Completely untested example...

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\web.config");
 var appSettingsElement = doc.Elements("appSettings").First();
 var reader = appSettingsElement.CreateReader();
 var settings = new AppSettingsSection();
 var method = typeof(AppSettingsSection).GetMethod("DeserializeSection",
                                                   BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                                   null,
                                                   null,
                                                   new[] { typeof(XmlReader) },
                                                   null );
 method.Invoke( settings, new [] { reader } );

 var value = settings["myParam"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable is **"YourVariable"**

Below line of code, returns file path.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourVariable"])
```

To access only the value of **web.config** then write this way.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourVariable"]
```

On your Project, you should insert **`System.configuration`** as **References**.

Comment: I think you understood my question wrong :)  
I'm trying to read a web.config file, not a parameter in the "default" web.config file of a running web application..

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line, is  --- No.  The appSettings configuration section is an xml element and its contents within the overall host applications ***Hiearchical Configuration Structure***, which can consist of ***many*** individual files.  Which file, (or files*), the appSettings section is in is determined by other settings within the confguration system.  So you can't really get at the settings with just a file pr path spec,  you must go through the built-in .Net confiuration system methods.

- based on other settings within the config system, a section can be placed in another file or indiviudal settings within a section can be located in different files, at different levels of the config system hiearchy)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've already tried `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(...)` - did you miss `config.AppSettings`?

```cs
// Resolved from the application root with "~"
// "~/MySubfolder/With/SpecialConfig/" works; values are read hierarchically
var relativePath = "~/";

var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(relativePath);

var myParam = config.AppSettings.Settings["myParam"].Value;

// You can use it to save settings too
config.AppSettings.Settings["myParam"].Value = "my new param value";

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```